# Postfix Server not accepted by Gmail

Tags: postfix, gmail

I have been sending emails from my server for 3 years now all of a sudden the emails bounce when sent to a gmail address - all other addresses are fine - I do not have a rDNS - my score with mailtester is 8.9

Comment: Read error from bounce, google error and take appropriate actions

Answer (score 0):

Try to register your server/domains with google postmaster tool, So Google will know your a real person that care about a/some domain(s), and it may helps clear your traffic about these domains.

In my experience I noticed it's helps to have an ipv6 address as well as an ipv4.